# clang: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found

Tags: macos, installation, hyperlink, compilation, llvm

After building and installing LLVM in /usr/local/ directory on MacOS 13.4, I use the following command to compile an example code:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/clang hello.c -o hello
```

I get the effor in the title, i.e., "fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found".
However, I could use the default clang successfully.

```
$ /usr/bin/clang hello.c -o hello
```

I use the following command to specify the directory on my machine:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/clang hello.c -o hello -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
```

I then get a new error:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

I expect that after building and installing LLVM on MacOS, I could use llvm-tool-chains to compile a C code correctly.

Comment: "Any idea?" Yes, it seems obvious you did not correctly build and install the LLVM toolchain. Since you didn't show us the steps you used to build the LLVM toolchain, and a link to the directions you followed, there is no way for us to figure out what you did wrong. Also, it might be useful to know why you are trying to install LLVM from source rather than using the macOS Xcode toolchain.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I later plan to develop some projects on LLVM. I have found the solution, i.e., using "clang -isysroot `xcrun --show-sdk-path`" to replace clang.